# Right Side navigation drawer icon always to the left

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm implementing navigation drawer. I want it from right to left. I succeeded to get the drawer list from right to left but the action bar icon always appears to left. I want it to the right as well. How can I do this ?

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="right"
    >

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
         />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I ended up with making custom action bar with button to right that has a background icon like the drawer icon. When click open/close the drawer

Comment: Thanks even I too ended up doing the same way. Thanks anyways