# Android navigation drawer toggle icon to right

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

My requirement is shown in the picture below  My navigation drawer should be opened from the right side. I have implemented this. My navigation drawer open from right to left. But the problem is toggle icon is always on the left side. How can I set toggle icon to the right?

I have checked the following SO questions, but none of them came to any help:

[Change toggle button image Icon In Navigation Drawer right to left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33497055/change-toggle-button-image-icon-in-navigation-drawer-right-to-left)

[Drawer Toggle in right Drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27330702/drawer-toggle-in-right-drawer)

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21580172/right-side-navigation-drawer-icon-always-to-the-left)

[image]

Here is what I have tried:

code for my layout **activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="end">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context="com.example.nav.MainActivity"
        android:foregroundGravity="right">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                android:foregroundGravity="right"
                android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="false" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"
        android:textAlignment="viewEnd" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Code for my activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        initNavigationDrawer();

    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public void initNavigationDrawer() {

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

                int id = menuItem.getItemId();

                switch (id){
                    case R.id.home:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Home",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        break;
                    case R.id.settings:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Settings",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case R.id.trash:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Trash",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        break;
                    case R.id.logout:
                        finish();

                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close){

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View v){
                super.onDrawerClosed(v);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View v) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(v);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                if (item != null && item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
                    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                    }
                    else {
                        drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                } else {
                    drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There's really no (practical) way to make `ActionBarDrawerToggle` do that, as it is always set on the start/left-side navigation button. However, that class is basically just a `DrawerListener` that manages a specialized `Drawable`, and wires an `ImageButton` to the `DrawerLayout`. We can put together something similar for an end/right-side drawer with an `ImageButton` that we can place on that same side in a `Toolbar` (which is required for this example).

```java
public class EndDrawerToggle implements DrawerLayout.DrawerListener {

    private final DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private final AppCompatImageButton toggleButton;
    private final int openDrawerContentDescRes;
    private final int closeDrawerContentDescRes;

    private DrawerArrowDrawable arrowDrawable;

    public EndDrawerToggle(DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar,
                           int openDrawerContentDescRes, int closeDrawerContentDescRes) {
        this.drawerLayout = drawerLayout;
        this.openDrawerContentDescRes = openDrawerContentDescRes;
        this.closeDrawerContentDescRes = closeDrawerContentDescRes;

        toggleButton = new AppCompatImageButton(toolbar.getContext(), null,
                R.attr.toolbarNavigationButtonStyle);
        toolbar.addView(toggleButton, new Toolbar.LayoutParams(GravityCompat.END));
        toggleButton.setOnClickListener(v -> toggle());

        loadDrawerArrowDrawable();
    }

    public void syncState() {
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)) {
            setPosition(1f);
        } else {
            setPosition(0f);
        }
    }

    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        loadDrawerArrowDrawable();
        syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerSlide(@NonNull View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
        setPosition(Math.min(1f, Math.max(0f, slideOffset)));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(@NonNull View drawerView) {
        setPosition(1f);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(@NonNull View drawerView) {
        setPosition(0f);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {}

    private void loadDrawerArrowDrawable() {
        arrowDrawable = new DrawerArrowDrawable(toggleButton.getContext());
        arrowDrawable.setDirection(DrawerArrowDrawable.ARROW_DIRECTION_END);
        toggleButton.setImageDrawable(arrowDrawable);
    }

    private void toggle() {
        final int drawerLockMode = drawerLayout.getDrawerLockMode(GravityCompat.END);
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerVisible(GravityCompat.END)
                && (drawerLockMode != DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
        } else if (drawerLockMode != DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED) {
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
        }
    }

    private void setPosition(float position) {
        if (position == 1f) {
            arrowDrawable.setVerticalMirror(true);
            setContentDescription(closeDrawerContentDescRes);
        } else if (position == 0f) {
            arrowDrawable.setVerticalMirror(false);
            setContentDescription(openDrawerContentDescRes);
        }
        arrowDrawable.setProgress(position);
    }

    private void setContentDescription(int resId) {
        toggleButton.setContentDescription(toggleButton.getContext().getText(resId));
    }
}
```

The `EndDrawerToggle` class works exactly the same way as `ActionBarDrawerToggle` does when used with a `Toolbar` (except the constructor call doesn't need an `Activity` argument): first instantiate the toggle, then add it as a `DrawerListener`, and sync it in the `Activity`'s `onPostCreate()` method. If you're already overriding the `Activity`'s `onConfigurationChanged()` method, you'll want to call the toggle's corresponding method there, like you would for an `ActionBarDrawerToggle`.

```java
private EndDrawerToggle drawerToggle;

public void initNavigationDrawer() {
    ...

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);

    drawerToggle = new EndDrawerToggle(drawerLayout,
                                       toolbar,
                                       R.string.drawer_open,
                                       R.string.drawer_close);

    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    drawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

---

If you have two drawers and need to use `ActionBarDrawerToggle` and `EndDrawerToggle` simultaneously, it is possible, but we'll need to handle intercepting and dispatching drawer motion events to the correct toggle.

If you prefer fewer classes, you could subclass `ActionBarDrawerToggle` and merge `EndDrawerToggle`'s functionality into it, dispatching each `DrawerListener` method call either to the `super` class, or to the local end toggle code.

However, composition is arguably much cleaner here, and it will let us use `EndDrawerToggle` as is. This example is a `DrawerListener` that relays `syncState()` and `onConfigurationChanged()` calls to each toggle, but dispatches the listener method calls only to the appropriate one, depending on which drawer is moving.

```java
public class DualDrawerToggle implements DrawerLayout.DrawerListener {

    private final DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private final Toolbar toolbar;
    private final ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    private final EndDrawerToggle endDrawerToggle;

    public DualDrawerToggle(Activity activity, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar,
                            int startDrawerOpenContDescRes, int startDrawerCloseContDescRes,
                            int endDrawerOpenContDescRes, int endDrawerCloseContDescRes) {
        this.drawerLayout = drawerLayout;
        this.toolbar = toolbar;
        this.actionBarDrawerToggle =
                new ActionBarDrawerToggle(activity, drawerLayout, toolbar,
                        startDrawerOpenContDescRes, startDrawerCloseContDescRes);
        this.endDrawerToggle =
                new EndDrawerToggle(drawerLayout, toolbar,
                        endDrawerOpenContDescRes, endDrawerCloseContDescRes);
    }

    public void syncState() {
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
        endDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        actionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Fixes bug in ABDT, which only reloads the up nav indicator, for some reason.
        final DrawerArrowDrawable dad = new DrawerArrowDrawable(toolbar.getContext());
        actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerArrowDrawable(dad);

        endDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerSlide(@NonNull View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
        if (isStartDrawerView(drawerView, drawerLayout.getLayoutDirection())) {
            actionBarDrawerToggle.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
        } else {
            endDrawerToggle.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(@NonNull View drawerView) {
        if (isStartDrawerView(drawerView, drawerLayout.getLayoutDirection())) {
            actionBarDrawerToggle.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        } else {
            endDrawerToggle.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(@NonNull View drawerView) {
        if (isStartDrawerView(drawerView, drawerLayout.getLayoutDirection())) {
            actionBarDrawerToggle.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        } else {
            endDrawerToggle.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {}

    @SuppressLint("RtlHardcoded")
    static boolean isStartDrawerView(View drawerView, int layoutDirection) {
        final int gravity = ((DrawerLayout.LayoutParams) drawerView.getLayoutParams()).gravity;
        final int horizontalGravity = gravity & GravityCompat.RELATIVE_HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK;
        if ((horizontalGravity & GravityCompat.RELATIVE_LAYOUT_DIRECTION) > 0) {
            return horizontalGravity == GravityCompat.START;
        } else {
            if (layoutDirection == View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL) {
                return horizontalGravity == Gravity.RIGHT;
            } else {
                return horizontalGravity == Gravity.LEFT;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Again, `DualDrawerToggle` works exactly the same way as `ActionBarDrawerToggle` does when used with a `Toolbar`, except for the extra content description resource IDs in the constructor.

Do note that the one `DualDrawerToggle` creates and manages both other toggles internally. You don't need to set up any other toggle instances in your `Activity`; just the `DualDrawerToggle`.

---

Notes:

- If you read through the code, you'll see that `EndDrawerToggle` – and therefore also `DualDrawerToggle` – can be readily adapted to put a toggle on pretty much anything that can display a `Drawable` and register clicks; e.g., a `FloatingActionButton`, an options menu item, a `TextView`'s compound drawable, etc. Simply replace the `AppCompatImageButton` with your target UI component, which can be passed in the constructor in place of the `Toolbar`, since the toggle won't be added to that anymore.
- Additionally, this could be modified to work with the start/left-aligned drawer, too – completely replacing `ActionBarDrawerToggle` – so that its toggle could be placed on those various components, as well.
- The `AppCompatImageButton` used here is a regular child of the `Toolbar`. If you're using a menu on the `Toolbar`, that menu will take precedence in the layout, and push the toggle inward. To keep it on the outside, you can modify the class as described above to set the toggle on an action menu item. I've an example of that in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47129045).
- That menu item example might also be useful if your design requires you use the decor-supplied `ActionBar` in lieu of your own `Toolbar`. Though `ActionBarDrawerToggle` can work with a decor-supplied `ActionBar`, this example can not, as is.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. I should mention that the end toggle is just a regular child of the `Toolbar`, so you'll need to take care if you add other child `View`s, or if you need a dropdown menu, which you'd probably want to implement manually to keep the alignment correct. Just a heads up. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot, but how do I change the toggle icon when using EndDrawerToggle?

Comment: @HeisenBerg I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Do you mean you want a different icon completely? That is, something other than the animated hamburger-arrow? If so, then you can just remove all of the `arrowDrawable` code from `EndDrawerToggle`, and set whatever image you want on `toggleButton`.

Comment: @MikeM. its work but my humberger icon menu move to center of toolbar, how can i fix it?

Comment: @RembulanMoon I'm not sure what you mean. If you have a menu in the `Toolbar`, too, then that automatically gets pinned to the very end, and `EndDrawerToggle` will be placed after that, toward the center. If that's your issue, you might have a look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47129045).

Answer (score 1):

In your android manifest add this line:

```
android:supportsRtl="true"
```

to your application, like so:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
```

Then in your onCreate method, add this line:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

WARNING::: This only works for SdkVersion 17+, so if your application targets a lower minimum SDK, you will have to create a custom menu and override the OnCreateOptions method(Unless there's another way which I'm not aware of, which is definitely possible).

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#supportsrtl

Comment: Sorry about that! For my app it only changes the menu! Glad you found the correct solution above though!

Comment: This is not a correct answer. You are forcing your activity and entire app to behave with RTL layout by default. Setting `View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL` will layout every textview and editexts to consider right side as the start like as it is in Arabic languages.

Comment: this solution is good and fast when your app is not multi language. tnx.