# Add button in top right toolbar corner programmatically

Tags: android

I'm trying to add a button in the top right corner of a toolbar, this is my code:

```
   mToolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    verified_btn = new Button(getActivity());
    verified_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_done_black_24dp);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(Toolbar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Toolbar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    params.width = 80;
    params.height = 80;

    verified_btn.setLayoutParams(params);
    verified_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    mToolbar.addView(verified_btn);
```

but this is the result:

[image]

I have tried different way, but is always there, how I can do?

Comment: `Toolbar` is not a child of `RelativeLayout`. That's why `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` rules will have no affect on it. You can try to add `gravity` to a button instead of rules.

Comment: I have already tried this: params.gravity = Gravity.END; and this params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT with no success

Comment: The right hand side of the toolbar is reserved for the menu. So you have to set it up as a menu item.

Comment: why dont you add it as menu item. So menu will start from right.

Comment: can you show me how add it as menu item? i'm in a fragment

Comment: You can add the menu same as you add in activity

Comment: onCreateOptionsMenu tell me that is never used in the fragment...

Comment: Specifying the `Gravity` will definitely work if you use `Toolbar.LayoutParams`. The right side isn't "reserved" for anything. Example:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/39136512

Comment: @MikeM. It was a wild guess :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your activity. This will add menu.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.right_menu, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_home:
            //Do Whatever you want to do here.
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Add new xml under `res > menu > right_menu.xml`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_home"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/title_activity_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

**app:showAsAction="always"** will always show your icon

**NOTE** : As you have fragment. you need to write this line in onCreate of fragment.

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

> [image]

Comment: onCreateOptionsMenu tell me that is never used in the fragment

Comment: thanks! you know how i can change the color? now it's black and I want it white

Comment: change the image to white color image

Comment: This is perfect.. But make app:showAsAction="ifRoom"