# Change positions of menu items and hamburger button for a right-side drawer

Tags: android, menu, menuitem, drawerlayout

In my `Toolbar`, I have a menu with one item "settings", and a `DrawerLayout` with a hamburger icon aligned to the right.

Now it looks like this:

[image]

I want the hamburger to be on the right, like this:

[image]

`menu.xml`:

```
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_48dp"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

`MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    //EndDrawerToggle is class for setup DrawerLayout with an end-aligned drawer
    private EndDrawerToggle drawerToggle;   

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context=this;
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        myToolbar.setTitle("");
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
        drawerToggle = new EndDrawerToggle(this,
                mDrawerLayout,
                myToolbar,
                R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close);
        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);    
        //....
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.settings) {
            //do smth
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

The `EndDrawerToggle` class is from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39136512/6522612).

Answer (score 2):

The menu in a `Toolbar` will always be pinned to the end, and there's not much that can be done about that, apart from directly modifying `Toolbar`'s behavior somehow, which would not be trivial.

One option would be to forgo the menu altogether, and add your own `Button` to the `Toolbar` for the settings. This might be a little unwieldy, though, since `EndDrawerToggle`'s `Button` is created and added dynamically, and so any other `View`s you'd want stacked before it on the end would have to be either created and added similarly, or juggled around after the toggle has been set.

However, with some modifications, we can get `EndDrawerToggle` to integrate directly with the menu, setting its toggle drawable as the icon on an always-shown menu item we add at the end. This actually ends up being a simpler class, since we don't need to provide an `ImageButton` for the drawable, as we did when adding the toggle directly to the `Toolbar`.

```
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.graphics.drawable.DrawerArrowDrawable;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;


public class EndMenuDrawerToggle implements DrawerLayout.DrawerListener {

    private final DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private final Toolbar toolbar;
    private final DrawerArrowDrawable arrowDrawable;
    private final int openDrawerContentDesc, closeDrawerContentDesc;
    private MenuItem toggleItem;

    public EndMenuDrawerToggle(DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar,
                               int openDrawerContentDesc, int closeDrawerContentDesc) {
        this.drawerLayout = drawerLayout;
        this.toolbar = toolbar;

        this.openDrawerContentDesc = openDrawerContentDesc;
        this.closeDrawerContentDesc = closeDrawerContentDesc;

        arrowDrawable = new DrawerArrowDrawable(toolbar.getContext());
        arrowDrawable.setDirection(DrawerArrowDrawable.ARROW_DIRECTION_END);
    }

    public void setToggleOnMenu(Menu menu) {
        toggleItem = menu.add(openDrawerContentDesc);
        toggleItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
        toggleItem.setIcon(arrowDrawable);
        toggleItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    toggle();
                    return true;
                }
            }
        );

        setPosition(drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END) ? 1f : 0f);
    }

    private void toggle() {
        final int drawerLockMode = drawerLayout.getDrawerLockMode(GravityCompat.END);
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerVisible(GravityCompat.END)
            && (drawerLockMode != DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
        }
        else if (drawerLockMode != DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED) {
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
        }
    }

    private void setPosition(float position) {
        if (position == 1f) {
            arrowDrawable.setVerticalMirror(true);
            toggleItem.setTitle(closeDrawerContentDesc);
        }
        else if (position == 0f) {
            arrowDrawable.setVerticalMirror(false);
            toggleItem.setTitle(openDrawerContentDesc);
        }
        arrowDrawable.setProgress(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
        setPosition(Math.min(1f, Math.max(0f, slideOffset)));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        setPosition(1f);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
        setPosition(0f);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {}
}
```

Initialization is basically the same; instantiate per usual, and add as a `DrawerListener` on the `DrawerLayout`.

```
drawerToggle = new EndMenuDrawerToggle(mDrawerLayout,
                                       myToolbar,
                                       R.string.open_drawer_end,
                                       R.string.close_drawer_end);
mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
...
```

The difference comes in the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method, where we pass the menu we inflate there to the toggle's `setToggleOnMenu()` method.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    drawerToggle.setToggleOnMenu(menu);

    return true;
}
```

We do not call `syncState()` with this class, as the drawable will be correctly synced in the method above.

[image: screenshot]

---

Do note that this example simply adds a `MenuItem` to the existing `Menu`, and sets that item as `SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS`. This will work as desired with the given menu, but if this is used with any menu that will have overflow items, the three-dot overflow icon is going to appear past the toggle.

In that case, if you still want the toggle at the very end, the overflow will have to be handled "manually"; e.g., by adding a custom item for the three-dot icon, and opening a separate menu in a popup.